# How do I make a form submission save data in a useState hook variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and JavaScript; currently looking at hooks. I have these two React functional components in an application I generated using Create React App:

`App.js`

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import NameTaker from './components/NameTaker'

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  if (name == null) {
    return <NameTaker onSubmit={submitHandler} />
  }
  return <p>Your name is: {name}</p>

  function submitHandler(e) {
    setName(e.value)
  }
}
```

and `NameTaker.js`

```
import React from 'react';

export default function NameTaker(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Please enter your name.</p>
      <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type='text' name='name' />
        </label>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is the render statement in `index.js`:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The application runs ok locally and the all the elements in `NameTaker.js` display correctly on the webpage.

When I fill out a name and click the button, I expect it to execute the callback function, store the name string inside the `name` variable, then when the `App` function component re-renders, the new name should be stored and `<p>Your name is: {name}</p>` should get returned instead of the form when the conditional statement is hit. But instead, when I click the button, the URL just changes to add `/?name=whatever` on the end, and the form remains on the page.

I tried modifying the program so that it gives the callback to the button instead of the form like this:
`<button onClick={props.onSubmit}>Submit</button>`
but there is not change in behaviour.

I tried adding `e.preventDefault();` before and then after the `setName` call in my callback function but that didn't work either.

The exact behaviour I'm looking for is:  *when name is `null`, return component displaying a form/input box, use callback to save the submitted name in state of the parent component, re-render parent component, but because state is no longer `null` return the paragraph displaying name instead of the form component.*

Can anyone show me how to do that please?

Comment: can you update the question with the render method also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to modify your `submitHandler` function as follows:

```
  function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.currentTarget.name.value)
  }
```

You need `e.preventDefault()` to stop the page from re-rendering, though often it isn't as needed as it used to be, I'm not entirely sure why.

In order to get values from the form, you have to specify which values you want. `e.currentTarget.name.value` gives you the current target (i.e. the form) then the `.name` part gives you the input of the form with the name or id of `name`, and then you can get the value of that input.

```js
const {useState} = React;
function NameTaker(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <p>Please enter your name.</p>
      <form onSubmit={props.onSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type='text' name='name' />
        </label>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  function submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setName(e.currentTarget.name.value)
  }
  if (name == null) {
    return <NameTaker onSubmit={submitHandler} />
  }
  return <p>Your name is: {name}</p>


}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import NameTaker from './components/NameTaker'

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);

  function submitHandler(e) {
    setName(e.target.value)
  }

 return(
    {!!name ? <p>Your name is: {name}</p> : <NameTaker onSubmit={submitHandler} />
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like how you've managed to implement it using only one return statement instead of using a conditional.
Would your approach also stop the page re-rendering when the form is submitted?